# Yii active form

Tags: activerecord, yii2, active-form

Im facing a issue with activeForms that extend the activeRecord.
Call to undefined function textInput()

field($model,'fname').textInput()->hint('Please Enter your Full Name');?>

I have defined the namespace: Yii helpers and the wii widgets active Form in the begining of the view.

Has anyone got this error? Can anyone tell me if i have missed out anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yuo have an error in the code use `->` instead of `.` for textInput()

like this :

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput()->hint('Please enter your name')->label('Name') ?>
```

Comment: I think on the left of the answer. under the useful/not useful row there is grey checkmark. click on it.

Comment: The useful are the upper arrow. below the arrows there should be a gray checkmark. You can also choose this to confirm that the answer is the right one

Comment: yep did that. Thanks.